# php.ini Error Reporting problem

Tags: php, ini, error-reporting

I get this error: `Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.`

In `php.ini` I have error reporting set as `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`.

Any idea how I can get rid of those warnings?

**EDIT:**
I want to fix the Error Reporting as there's other kinds of Warnings showing up.

**EDIT 2:**
All warnings were date.timezone related.

Thank you.

Comment: `Error_Reporting` is not the problem, you should fix the errors, not suppress them. If you want to post some of the errors you get, we may be able to assist you in correcting them.

Comment: They are not errors, they are warnings.

Comment: It's PHPMyAdmin that is throwing them, I have no intention of fixing them. But thank you for the offer. :)

Comment: They are errors, they are just not *fatal* errors, depending on how you look at them. A notice is also an error, but it is less important than a warning. A warning is less important than a Parser error etc. It is just the level of the error. If it is PHPMyAdmin, throw a `.htaccess` file inside the directory and omit the errors just for that application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find this section in the `php.ini` file:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Some/Timezone
```

Uncomment it (remove the ;) and change it to be the correct timezone. For a list of supported timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thanks, there are other warnings. I want to fix the Error Reporting setting.

Comment: Hmm, you and zzarbi were right. All of the other errors were `date.timezone` related. I didn't bother to read as there were tons of them, but your answer fixed it and Error Reporting is working normally. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Look for:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
; date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

and Uncomment this line:

```
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

And choose your time zone...

Comment: Thanks, I want to understand why Error Reporting isn't doing what it's supposed to do, there are other warnings I did not mention in the question.

Comment: @Francisc: `error_reporting` is doing exactly what it was setup to do, alert you when you have an error. You can hide the errors by adding  `~ E_WARNING`, but why not just take care of the errors and fix them?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is throwing them (latest stable download too).

Answer (score 1):

you could just catch that warning using the @ operator. Turning off warnings is ill advised in my view

Comment: I would say in general stay away from the `@` operator. It has it's uses, but suppressing errors that you can correct yourself and not get, would be much more preferred.

Comment: I don't mean to surpress them, just divert them from the stage. I send mine to firephp

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code in your php file.
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
URL: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
```